# SQL find in string separated by commas

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I am looking to build a query which can find values in string. For eg my column demo has following 2 rows:

```
1,2,121,43
343,21
```

My current query is:

```
select * from table where demo like '%21%'
```

However, this returns  both the rows. I want to look for the exact match in the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
select * from table 
where find_in_set(21, demo) > 0
```

#### But actually you should really change your table structure. Never store multiple values in one column!

Comment: why you dont recommend string multiple values in one column. what could be the issue?

Comment: It is slow, it is dirty DB design and you had a problem with it yourself - that is why you asked this question.